# submitting the attendance radio buttons to the database

Tags: php, sql, radio-button

am making this system and am stuck in a problm need help
my database has table attandence where fields are
    `att_id`    `s_no`  `std_reg_no`    `std_name`  `semester_id`   `total_classes` `present`   `absent`
i have made this form in which students of specific semester are displayed and radio buttons to mark whether a student is present or absent . i used s_no of students in the name of radio through an array following is the code

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" name="chk" value="update">
<table border="groove" cellpadding="15px">
<tr>
<td>s.no</td>
<td>Reg. No</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>Present</td>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$id=  $row['s_no'];
$no[]=  $row['std_reg_no'];
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['s_no']."</td><td>";  
echo $row['std_reg_no']."</td><td>";
echo $row['std_name']."</td>";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='attend[$id]' value='present' >Present &nbsp; <input type='radio' name='attend[$id]' value='ab'>absent</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='btnAbsent' value='submit'>";

echo a;
?>
</form>
```

what i want to do in php is to take each radiobutton if it is present add +1 to present and if absent +! to absent please someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i have increment +1 if you select any person as Present and i have decrement -1 if you have selected any person as Absent...

Database table structure Query

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance` (
  `att_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `s_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_reg_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `std_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `semester_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_classes` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `present` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `absent` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" name="chk" value="update">
<table border="groove" cellpadding="15px">
<tr>
<td>s.no</td>
<td>Reg. No</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>Present</td>
</tr>

<?php
include_once("yourconfig.php"); //add here your db config file
extract($_POST);
//After Click on Submit Call this
if(isset($btnAbsent))
{
 foreach($attend as $atn_key=>$atn_value)
 {
  if($atn_value=="present")
  {
   $upd_qry="UPDATE attendance SET present=present+1 where s_no='".$atn_key."'";
   mysql_query($upd_qry);
  }
  elseif($atn_value=="absent")
  {
   $upd_qry="UPDATE attendance SET absent=absent-1 where s_no='".$atn_key."'";
   mysql_query($upd_qry);
  }
 }
}


//Default call this
$check_exist_qry="select * from attendance";
$rs=mysql_query($check_exist_qry);
$total_found=mysql_num_rows($rs);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
 $id=  $row['s_no'];
 $no[]=  $row['std_reg_no'];
 echo "<tr><td>";
 echo $row['s_no']."</td><td>";  
 echo $row['std_reg_no']."</td><td>";
 echo $row['std_name']."</td>";
 echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='attend[$id]' value='present' >Present &nbsp; <input type='radio' name='attend[$id]' value='absent'>absent</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='btnAbsent' value='submit'>";
?>
</form>
```

[image]

if you found this is a helpful than give this answer as a correct and give vote for this solution

Comment: thank u sooo much Mahendra Pumbhadiya it worked...
the name of table is atendance for someone who wants to use his code use attendance instead of student_reg as table name... thank u once again :)

Comment: Most Welcome motan, i have changed above table as as attendance instead of student_reg, give vote for this answer and give this answer as a correct answer if your problem is solved..